# How to publish frontier locations from occupancy maps

Tags: ros, rviz, exploration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to figure out how to publish either markers or other data representing unexplored frontiers to rviz or another node. By frontier, I mean the boundary between open and unexplored space in a 2D occupancy map. I know that hector_exploration_planner does this internally and generates a single goal, after which hector_exploration_controller moves the robot to the said goal. However, I would like to play an intermediary role in the goal-determination process and then manually move the vehicle to the goal I select. Does anyone have any recommendations for ros packages that determine and publish all frontiers, or alternatively, information on how to use hector_exploration_explorer to publish this information?

Much appreciated! Please let me know if any additional information would be useful.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193070/how-to-publish-frontier-locations-from-occupancy-maps/) by [crzx5](https://answers.ros.org/users/20244/crzx5/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2014-09-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`frontier_exploration` publishes frontier locations as a pointcloud, but also only for visualization purposes. You would have to modify the `explore_server` state machine in order to make external frontier decisions.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I used nav_msgs/GridCells to publish all frontier cells and show them in RVIZ. But this was only for visualization, not to do any further processing in another node.

---

Originally posted by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) with karma: 1658 on 2014-09-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1